# neo4j Unable to establish connection in 5000ms message from cypher shell

Tags: shell, neo4j, cypher

Running Neo4j Enterprise 3.5.2
This only occurs when the machine is very busy with 35+ concurrent queries.
The system has a large memory with appropriate Java setting.

Is there any way to increase this timeout ?

Comment: Please share your actual config settings for heap and page-cache, and the io-spec of your disk and the type of workloads you run.

Comment: Java Memory sizes are:
    dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=200g
    dbms.memory.heap.max_size=200g
    dbms.memory.pagecache.size=240g
     
The database sits on a Raid-0 stripe group of fast SSD's.
Single large node. The error occurs when there are 35+ queries running in parallel.
    IOWait time is 0.1%